# Set footnote single-space in double-space document

Tags: footnotes, revtex, setspace

The title says it all.  How do I set the footnote spacing to single-spaced?  At the bottom of the picture, you can see that the spacing between the footnotes is slightly less than the spacing between the lines in each footnote.  I would like to keep the spacing between footnotes as it is but to decrease line spacing in the individual footnotes.  Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\begin{document}
\title{Exciting Title about Paper Subject}
  \author{Hodor P. Hodor}
  \affiliation{High Powered University, Antarctica}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
    This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  This is the abstract.  
\end{abstract}
\maketitle


This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.\footnote{This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.  This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.}  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.\footnote{This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.  This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.  This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.}  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  This is the main body of text.  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this solution you have to adjust the values of `\footnotesep` and `\setspace@singlespace` manually:

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\footnotesep=9pt
  
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\setspace@singlespace}{0.8}
  {}{}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}

\title{Exciting Title about Paper Subject}
\author{Hodor P. Hodor}
\affiliation{High Powered University, Antarctica}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
The abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

This is the main body of text.\footnote{This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.  This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.}  

This is the main body of text.\footnote{This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.  This is a footnote where I want to have single spacing instead of the current double spacing.}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You are really cool.